# Calendar weekend days

Tags: solspace-calendar

I am using solspace calendar. The weekend in our country is during Friday and Saturday. I would like to show the dates which are during the weekend in different color. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Please, try this:

```
{if '{event_start_date format="%w"}' > 4} class="weekend" {/if}
```

[`%w` returns the day](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/date_variable_formatting.html) of the week, from 0, for Sunday, to 6, Saturday.

[`event_start_date`](http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/events//#event_start_date) is available on both `exp:calendar:events` and `exp:calendar:cal`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please show me how to use it within exp:calendar:cal. Shall I use it between events tags

Comment: Please, edit your question and add your code. I can use it for my sample.

Answer (score 0):

{exp:calendar:cal   calendar_id="218" enable="categories"  {if segment_3 == ''}  date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last" {/if} 
{if segment_3 != ""}   date_range_start="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-01"                date_range_end="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-last" {/if} }            {display_each_month}            
                
                    
                        
                           
                          
                        
{date format="%F %Y"}                        
                      
                
                
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                        
                                            
{display_each_day_of_week}                                            
                                                
{day_of_week_short}                                            
                                            
{/display_each_day_of_week}                                        
                                    
                                    
                                        
{display_each_week}                                         
                                            
{display_each_day}                                            
{if day_in_current_month}                                                
                                                   
                                                        
{date format="%j"}

                                            
{if:else}                                                
                                                    
                                                    
 {date format="%j"}                                              
{/if}                                            


{if day_in_current_month}
{display_each_hour}                                                
{events}                                                    
 0} index_difference_{all_day_event_index_difference}{/if} "> 

                                                    


                                                    
{/events}                                                
{/display_each_hour}
{/if}






{/display_each_day} 
 
{/display_each_week} 
 

                        
                    
                
            
            
{/display_each_month}            
{/exp:calendar:cal}